# Display users with most posts in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to display the first 5 top users with most posts like this: User1 (5 Posts) User5 (3 Posts) User2 (2 Posts) .... –
in my `AppServiceProvider.php`

```
view()->composer('questions.side', function($view){
$users = User::leftJoin('questions','user.id','=','questions.user_id'‌​‌​‌​‌​)
->selectRaw('‌​us‌​er‌​.*, count(questions.user_id) AS total')
->groupBy('users.id')
->orderBy('total','DESC')
->skip(‌​‌​‌​0)
->take(5)
->get‌​()‌​;

 $view->with('users', $users);

});
```

in my side view:

```
foreach($usersas $user) {
  var_dump($user);
}
```

but I get this problem:

> FatalErrorException in AppServiceProvider.php line 18: syntax error,
>   unexpected '‌​‌​‌​‌​' (T_STRING)

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of sql syntax error 
change your $users from

```
$users = User::leftJoin('questions','user.id','=','questions.user_id'‌​‌​‌​‌​)->selectRaw('‌​us‌​er‌​.*, count(questions.user_id) AS total')->groupBy('users.id')->orderBy('total','DESC')->skip(‌​‌​‌​0)->take(5)->get‌​()‌​;
```

to this

```
$users = DB::table('users')->leftJoin('questions','user.id','=','questions.user_id'‌​‌​‌​‌​)->select('‌​us‌​er‌​.*', count('questions.user_id') 'AS total')->orderBy('total','DESC')->skip(‌​‌​‌​0)->take(5)->get‌​()‌​;
```

I recommend you to var_dump($users) before you parse them inside the blade file

Comment: It's give me the some error: syntax error, unexpected '‌​‌​‌​‌​' (T_STRING)
i try this: view()->composer('questions.side', function($view){ $users = User::leftJoin('questions','users.id','=','questions.user_id'‌​‌​‌​‌​)->selectRaw('‌​us‌​er‌s​.*, count(questions.user_id) AS total')->groupBy('users.id')->orderBy('total','DESC')->skip(‌​‌​‌​0)->take(5)->get‌​()‌​; 
   $view->with('users', $users); });
Not worked to ..

Comment: Have you tried to change the code to what I typed for you ? your code has syntax error it won't work like so

Comment: I've modified the code I think no need for grouping by because you want one row for each user